# Custom File Support on my Android App

Tags: java, android, security, import, export

i am planning to work with my app that's main function is like Schedule Making, with Navigation Drawer and ExpandableListView ..

i am also planning to add an import export feature with a custom file extension .. and the content within the custom file will be encrypted so when a user tries to open it up using text editor tools, it will not be altered .. is there anyway i can do this ? ..

i've searched around and found others a little too far from my objective .. thanks :)

Comment: "the content within the custom file will be encrypted so when a user tries to open it up using text editor tools, it will not be altered" - what do you mean by that? Do you want the user not be able to look at it, or do you want to have integrity protection? Also do you want it to be encrypted with a key given by the user (encrypted backups) or in some way the legitimate user cannot access the data (in a DRM fashion)? The latter falls into the discipline of obfuscation, rather than cryptography.

Comment: sorry about that. what i meant is the custom file can only be read by my app and my app alone. MY UI would look like this http://i.imgur.com/aZj90Yz.png .. i am planning to add an Import/Export Feature to my app that exports the information that can be found inside the ExpandableListView .. and before the information is exported the app will first encrypt it so that it will not be opened up in any text editor, but the exported file will then be readable for other devices that has my app .. sorry for my bad english and explanation, i am not fluent tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the vast majority of users from reading your files you can use the 16th century cipher ["Vigenère"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher). Choose any byte string `key` and encrypt/decrypt via

```
byte [] encryptOrDecrypt(byte[] key, byte[] input){
    byte [] result = new byte[input.length];
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        result[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % key.length];
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Warning: I have not run this code, it probably contains a bunch of syntax errors.)

You are out of luck, though, if you try to protect against a dedicated attacker. In the end one can always reverse engineer your apk file. So whatever kind of cryptography you are using, if your program can read the file, so can a dedicated attacker.

Comment: thanks ! .. i already have had studied Vigenere Cryptography :) .. well, i a hacker modifies it, it doesn't really matter .. i'll find a way though .. well, how about the custom file support ?

Comment: Erm, I'm not sure what you're asking. Your file format will be pretty non-standard once you implement Vigenère encryption. @n00b